# Kubernetes suddenly stopped being able to connect to server

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud

I was successfully able to connect to the kubernetes cluster and work with the services and pods. At one point this changed and everytime I try to connect to the cluster I get the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\xxx> kubectl get pods
Unable to connect to the server: error parsing output for access token command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Cloud SDK\\google-cloud-sdk\\bin\\gcloud.cmd config config-helper --format=json": yaml: line 4: could not find expected ':'
```

I am unsure of what the issue is. Google unfortunately doesn't yield any results for me either.

I have not changed any config files or anything. It was a matter of it working one second and not working the next.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the default auth plugin for GKE might be buggy on windows. kubectl is trying to run gcloud to get a token to authenticate to your cluster. If you run kubectl config view you can see the command it tried to run, and run it yourself to see if/why it fails.

As Alexandru said, a workaround is to use Google Application Default Credentials. Actually, gcloud container has built in support for doing this, which you can toggle by setting a property:

`gcloud config set container/use_application_default_credentials true` Try running this or set environment variable

`%CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_USE_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_CREDENTIALS%` to true.

Referenced from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44660833/11317776)

The workaround for this issue being:

`gcloud container clusters get-credentials <cluster-name>` If you dont know your cluster name find it by `gcloud container clusters list` Finally, if those don't have issues, do `gcloud auth application-default login` and login with relative details

Comment: That gives me some direction. Unfortunately it didn't fix the issue. If I run the command the error throws saying didn't work, I get what it was looking for which is the credentials JSON file. The access and id tokens are there and the file itself opened up fine. 

Command: gcloud config config-helper --format=json

Where can I change environment variables?

Comment: do `export CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_USE_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_CREDENTIALS = true`

Comment: Oh! you're using windows. `setx CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_USE_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_CREDENTIALS "true"`

Comment: Put that into your command line, where you typed `kubectl get pods` 
Also, you really want to install powershell and get familiar.

Comment: Can you tell me the output of `gcloud container clusters get-credentials <cluster-name>` If you dont know your cluster name find it by `gcloud container clusters list` Finally, if those don't have issues, do `gcloud auth application-default login` and login with relative details

Comment: After some mucking about I got it fixed. I followed your instructions and ended up changing around the set clusters, re-logging in using that gcloud command you mentioned. Apologies but I wasn't sure at exactly at which point for any future readers. Thank you Daudnadeem.

Comment: My pleasure @BURGERFLIPPER101 I'm glad I managed to help you out! If possible, edit my answer so the next person doesn't have a difficult time!